# Inserting the name of the app within the iOS icon = against Guidelines?

Tags: ios, icons, naming

One of my customer provides me an icon including the name of the app Within the icon. I don't find it necessary since the name of the app is inserted below the icon and the icon should contain an explicit logo of the app, nothing else. Not sure it's compliant with iOS guidelines I've looked into the iOS HIG, nothing found.
Any idea on that ?
Thank

Answer (score 1):

I think you can. However you should consider the Apple App Icons Guidelines.

You can see the  App Icons Guideline [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's against Guidelines, but your app will not be rejected for this, you can find a lot of applications that have name on icon => [Youtube Application](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/youtube/id544007664?mt=8)